# Window.fbAsyncInit is not accessed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have a script in file cshtml to use facebook API, but function window.fbAsyncInit is not called. How can I call this func?

This function show "flag 1" in console but flag 2 is not

```html
<div onclick="likeb()">1</div>
```

```
function likeb() {

    console.log("flag 1");

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '295590887998480',
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v3.3'
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });

        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, { scope: 'user_likes,user_photos,user_link,user_posts,user_friends,publish_to_groups,manage_pages' });


        FB.login(function (response) {
            FB.api(
                '/me/feed', 'post',
                { "message": "Hé lô mấy bạn ;)" },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            );
        }, { scope: 'user_likes,user_photos,user_link,user_posts,user_friends,publish_to_groups,manage_pages' });

        console.log("flag 2");
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Logged in and authenticated');
        } else {
            console.log('Not authenticated');
        }
    }

}
```

This function show "flag 1" in console but flag 2 is not

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you get a facebook popup when you click and the code runs?

Comment: I use chrome. nothing happens

Comment: What happens when you call this url in the browser? https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js

Comment: I follow the instructions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Comment: When I try your code on my pc, it seems to work fine. I get a facebook popup where Im prompted for login credentials. The reason for I asked you about the https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js link is because you can check if url returns the necessary script..

Comment: I just coppy code to new app, It's fine, but my project is not, how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the cshtml code? Are you receiving any other errors?

Comment: can you chat with me on facebook, or gmail,..... ? 
this mine: facebook.com/ILMinionFV 
Thank you!